# The GCM response is not correct, missing },{

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending a GCM push message (less then 1000) with:

```
$Regids = mysql_query("SELECT regid FROM $tabel WHERE active = '1'");
$result_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Regids)){
    $result_array[] = $row['regid'];
}

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:key=' . $serverApiKey
);

 $data = array(
    'registration_ids' => $result_array,
    'data' => array(
        'type' => 'New',
        'title' => 'LH',
        'msg' => ''.$msj.''
    )
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
if ($headers)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

When I print the `$result` to check (and use for updating the database) it shows:

```
{"multicast_id":000,"success":274,"failure":75,"canonical_ids":13,"results":[{"message_id":"123"},{"message_id":"123"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"123"},{"message_id":"123"},{"registration_id":"456","message_id":"123"}]}
```

There is no },{ between every (canonical) `registration_id` and the next (success) `message_id` or `error`.
(I shortened the response to make it readable)

So my update part fails

```
$result = json_decode($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result->{'results'}); $i++) { 
    if ($result->{'results'}[$i]->{'message_id'}) {
        ...
    } elseif($result->{'results'}[$i]->{'error'}) {
        ...
    } elseif ($result->{'results'}[$i]->{'registration_id'}) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Does someone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the response you got is correct . A message for which you get a canonical registration id is still accepted by Google and is therefore successful , and that's why you get a message id in addition to the canonical registration id for that message . That's why there are no brackets after the canonical registration id.

Comment: Aha, thanks for your explanation. Clear! Any id how to adjust my update part because this way it only gets message_id and error. The registration_id does not show up because the different form, I guess.

Comment: I solved it with 1e if: registration_id, 2e: error, 3e: message_id, but I think a better solution is possible?